# Android , Fragments into fragment into activity communication

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is my problem.In my android app I have "Activity 1" that contains "fragment1". "Fragment1" in his layout contains a "viewpager" with 3 pages "fragment3", "fragment4" and "fragment5". I "Activity 2" that contains "Fragment2". Now I want to execute an action in "Fragment" 1, 2 or 3 and then launch the activity2, so send data from  fragments 3,4 or 5 and display them in the fragment 6. I am willing to go through "interfaces" who will be in the  fragments 3, 4, 5  to respect the java standards. Since, I can not, I get errors. In landscape mode the fragments 2 and 3 are side by side

[image]

For example here are

Fragment1

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment implements Frag3.Communicator{

    private ViewPager mPager = null;
    private TabLayout mTab = null;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    private int p;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag4, container, false);

        mPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mTab = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        mPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
        mTab.setupWithViewPager(mPager);


        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String data) {

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if(position == 0)
            {
                fragment = new Frag1();
                p = position;

            }
            if(position == 1)
            {
                fragment = new Frag2();
                p = position;
            }
            if(position == 2)
            {
                fragment = new Frag3();
                p = position;
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            if(position == 0)
            {
                return "Tab 1";
            }
            if(position == 1)
            {
                return "Tab 2";
            }
            if(position == 2)
            {
                return "Tab 3";
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment 3

```
public class Frag3 extends Fragment {

    Button b;

    Communicator comm;
    public void setCommunicator(Communicator c)
    {
        comm = c;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    public interface Communicator
    {
        public void respond(String data);
    }

    public void openSub()
    {
        comm.respond("Sub ouvert depuis le fragment numéro 1");
    }
}
```

Fragment2

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

    private TextView tv;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag5, container, false);
        tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.frag5Tv);
        return v;
    }

    public void changeData(String data)
    {
        tv.setText(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but your question is not clear

Comment: i have fragment inside activity, and in the layout of this fragment a view pager, with 3 tabs, so 3 fragments. I read that communication between fragments must done going through interfaces. So in one of my 3 tabs i have interface and i want when i do an action in this fragment i lunch another activity ( in this other activity there is a fragment inside ) and show some changes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should unify architecture either with one Activity or with two Activities but for both orientations. In case with one Activity you can communicate via Activity's interface. Just replace Fragment1 with Fragment2 to change view.
In case with two Activities you can communicate via startActivityForResult/onActivityResult methods.